# How do I add CPU frequency governors to the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu-frequency

CPU frequency scaling in Linux is by default performed via a governor, which as far as I know is included in the kernel. So far, on PC/server Linux kernels I've only seen the userspace, powersave, performance, ondemand and conservative governors. However, on custom Android ROMs and kernels I've seen many other better governors, such as pegasusq (CyanogenMod), zzmoove (Boeffla Kernel), lulzactiveq (Googy Max Kernel) and devilq (Devil2 Kernel).

Would it be a good idea to use a cell phone frequency governor on a laptop? And if so, how could I possibly add them to my Linux kernel? I use Gentoo so I'm already used to compiling my kernel if necessary.

Comment: Just for reference, the pegasusq governor is a Samsung made governor which is present in stock Samsung kernels too, thus has nothing do with CyanogenMod per se.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to find the code for that specific governor and add it to your kernel before recompiling it or you can also write the proper `Makefile` and compile the governor as a module. The code for the governor should be in `drivers/cpufreq/`. For example, for the `lulzactive` governor: [drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_lulzactive.c](https://github.com/tegrak/lulz-kernel_gt-i9100/blob/master/kernel/drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_lulzactive.c)